# How create datasource for select from array of data in same form?

Tags: alpacajs

I'd like make the select field in alpaca forms, which get data from other array in same form.

can't understand how it's make from documentation

Comment: Can you be more specific? do you want to change select data after array updates? can you prototype/describe more your case?

Comment: Yes. This case. For example my form from json schema have two fields. One field is select, other is array of select items. First i edit array, and after select one value from array to select field.

Answer (score 0):

```
{"schema":{
  "properties":{
     "selectedEventType":{
         "type":"number",
         "title":"Event Type"
      }
  }
}
```

and...

```
{"options":{
  "fields":{
      "selectedEventType":{
        "type": "select",
        "dataSource": "/mycontroller/options/event",
        "removeDefaultNone": true,
        "helper": "list of selectable options"
       }
  }
}
```

in your REST api for (/mycontroller/options/event) return data that looks like this:

```
{[ {"text":"one","value":1},{"text":"two","value":2},{"text":"three","value":3} ]}
```

Comment: Thx, but i asked about data in document, not from api

Answer (score 0):

So, without your code, it's hard to say. Something that may help is to use the postRender function and subscribe the second field to the first field. So when the first field is changed, it updates the second field's options based on the selection of the first.

Here is a working JS Fiddle for this idea: https://jsfiddle.net/bsunderland/78hybL3v/2/#&togetherjs=NUczl1pesg

In the example above, the options for field 2 are dependent on the selection in field 1. Below, I also included some example code for doing this via a server-side call. I know that is not the request for this question but I still think it can be useful:

```
"postRender": function(control) {
            var parentType = control.childrenByPropertyId["Parent_LookupTypeCode"]; //Grab the Parent Lookup Type Object
            var parentCode = control.childrenByPropertyId["Parent_LookupCode"]; //Grab the Parent Lookup Object
            parentCode.subscribe(parentType, function(val) {//Subscribe parentCode to changes to parentType
                // alert(val);
                if(!val) {//val = value of parentType
                    val="Metrics"; //If missing, do nothing
                }
                else{
                    this.options.dataSource = "./ExtraStuff/Load_Lookups.php?q=" + val; //Load values based on val of parentType
                }

                this.refresh(); //Refresh the form. This is needed. Without it, the updated options won't show
            });
        }
```